# What methods are there for drying oils?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I am trying to generate thin films of sample for TXRF testing, but my samples contain a significant amount of oil in them. My slides are analyzed vertically, so the oil simply drips off.

I have access to a muffle furnace and can ash my sample, but I am hoping to check for mercury content and that will drive it away into the air.

What are some things I could do to turn these samples into a stable film?

Comment: [TXRF](https://www.spectroscopyeurope.com/article/total-reflection-x-ray-fluorescence-technique-multi-elemental-analysis-food)?

Comment: You can dry wet samples, but not oily samples.

Comment: Drying oil is a thing, though.

Comment: @Karsten yes, that method! It's a great tool for measuring PPM/PPB levels of metals in things, however the sample needs to be a thin film on a disc in order to work. Perhaps there's a way to convert the oils into something more stable?

Comment: I believe you mean that you want to firmly fix the oil so that it does not drip- not remove water from it. The only way is perhaps to freeze it. For a chemist, drying only means removing water.

Comment: @AChem, there are "drying oils" such as linseed oil, that *oxidize* in air to form a "dry" film.

Comment: Could you coat the slide with an oleophilic substance (e.g., melamine: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsami.7b13626)? Or chill it in liquid N2 until it congeals on the slide (though you'd have to get it into the analyzer before it warms)?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, After adding oils to another oil "sample", the concentration values will be wrong from XRF. The sample has been diluted in a non-reproducible way.